# How get ImageView's image from Listview and send it to an activity with Intent?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-activity, imageview

I have a custom listview which has TextView and ImageView, so far I've managed to move text from one activity to another but I also have to transfer the image, as I can do?

```
 mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {

   //TEXT
     String URL = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.descripcion)).getText().toString();
  //IMAGE?


      Intent i = new Intent(Lista_productos.this, pruebalista.class); 

      i.putExtra("URL", URL);
      startActivity(i); 
      }      
});
```

And then, my other class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pruebaa);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String url = intent.getStringExtra("URL");

        TextView txtCambiado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pruebaa);
        txtCambiado.setText(url);

                //IMAGE?

    }
```

Comment: You show the image in the listview by calling its id, isn't it? Then you can send the id to another activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can set image's data as view's tag when you set it to imageView on your adapter's getView method and onItemClick you can get data by view.getTag() to send with intent.

**Edit: Assuming that you set your imageView's image somehow form url, so i'll send that url**

```
private class YourAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SomeObject> {
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageLoader.displayImage(yourImageView, yourImageUrl);
    convertView.setTag(yourImageUrl);

    return convertView;
}
}

OnItemClickListener yourItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String yourImageUrl = view.getTag().toString();
    // You can now send this image to next activity via intent
}
}
```

ImageLoader.displayImage is just an fake made-up method, however you load your image...